# python mechanize fails / webbrowser works

Tags: python, mechanize

I am having trouble with mechanize

```
br = Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.open("https://portail.appli/DACLogin?op=c&url=aHsL2luZGV4LnBocA==")
```

this does not open the page while the webbrower.open() does the trick

```
webbrowser.open("https://portail.appli/DACLogin?op=c&url=aHsL2luZGV4LnBocA==")
```

What am I getting wrong?

thanks

Comment: I don't really understand the question because `mechanize`s `Browser.open()` does something completely different than `webbrowser.open()` (assuming the `webbrowser` module from the standard library). Please tell us what you want to do/expect from the functions and in which way their behaviour differs from what you actually get.

Comment: thank you blackjack, sorry for the confusing question. I would like to login to a page. After that I would like the function to open the browser and the page to be visible

Comment: Maybe you are looking for something like [Selenium Remote-Control](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/index.jsp)‽